# Загрузка файла (картинки - jpg в BLOB-поле)

Tags: mysql, delphi, blob

Пытаюсь загрузить файл в БД (MySQL), в blob-поле (маленькую, до 50kb картинку - формат jpg).

Но вот что-то у меня идёт не так:

```
var
  ImgPath: String;

begin  
  ImgPath:=ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0))+'data\photo.jpg';
  ADOQuery1.Close;
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  ADOQuery1.SQL.ADD('UPDATE exam_users SET `photo`=(:fphoto) WHERE `number` = 94');
  ADOQuery1.parameters.parambyname('fphoto').LoadFromFile(ImgPath, ftBlob);

  ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
  ADOQuery1.Close;
end;
```

также пробовал и так:

```
var
  ImgPath: String;
  fs:TFileStream;

begin    
  ImgPath:=ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0))+'data\photo.jpg';
  fs :=TFileStream.Create(ImgPath, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
  ADOQuery1.SQL.ADD('UPDATE exam_users SET `photo`=(:fphoto) WHERE `number` = 94');
  ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('fphoto').LoadFromStream(fs, ftBlob);
  ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
  fs.Free;
  ADOQuery1.Close;
end;
```

Все эти два примера выдают одну ошибку:

> Project Project2.exe raised exception class EOleException with message 'Аргументы имеют неверный тип, выходят за пределы допустимого диапазона или вступают в конфликт друг с другом'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вернулся снова в проекте к этому вопросу.
Оказывается если в первом примере данное сообщение при компиляции проекта игнорировать, то всё прекрасно записывается в БД!
А когда файл проекта скопмилирован и просто запускается на исполнение, то ни какого сообщения программа не выдаёт и всё срабатывает на 100%.
Файл без каких-либо ошибок загружается в Blob-поле БД.
Так что:

```
ImgPath:=ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0))+'data\photo.jpg';
ADOQuery1.Close;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;

ADOQuery1.SQL.ADD('UPDATE exam_users SET `photo`=(:blob_photo) WHERE `number` = 94');
ADOQuery1.parameters.parambyname('blob_photo').LoadFromFile(ImgPath, ftBlob);

ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
ADOQuery1.Close;
```

работоспособный код.

Answer (score 1):

Что то мне подсказывает что тип поля не совсем ftBlob, я бы поэкспериментировал с другими значениями. Я так понимаю у Вас в базе тип поля `text`?

При работе с потоком еще попробуйте установить позицию в 0.

```
fs := TFileStream.Create...
fs.Position = 0;
```

На крайний случай можно написать как то так.

```
ImgPath := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0))+'data\photo.jpg';
ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := 'select `photo` from exam_users where `number` = 94';
ADOQuery1.Open;
TBlobField(ADOQuery1.FieldByName('photo')).LoadFromFile('c:\sample_2.jpg');
```

Но это не решает Вашу проблему. И если в базе есть уже данные, они сперва тянутся на клиент, а потом обновляются.

Comment: "Я так понимаю у Вас в базе тип поля text" - Как так blob-поле, а тип его текст? Погодите, это вы в элемент BlobField добавили картинку из файла. А я пытаюсь в БД засунуть картинку. `UPDATE table_name SET 'photo'=[картинка]`. Поэтому и `ExecSQL` у меня, а не `Open`. Или же только так, через BlobField и другого выход нет? Не может же такого в Delphi быть, чтобы нельзя было без "посредника".

Comment: ругается, что нет поля `photo` в  `TBlobField(ADOQuery1.FieldByName('photo')).LoadFromFile(ImgPath+'data\photo.jpg');`. Хотя сам запрос срабатывает верно, отдаёт поле `photo` от 94-го id.