# Как записать JSON в MySQL

Tags: mysql, delphi

Пробую записать JSON в MySql, но не получается из-за слэшей и кавычек которые находятся в JSON'не. Как можно сделать?

Знаю что в PHP есть такая функция mysql_real_escape_string, ну как же быть с Delphi?

Comment: Используйте параметры.

Comment: Можно ещё попробовать как blob.

Comment: [Тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/566771/2110) пример загрузки картинки в блоб поле. У вас будет что то подобное.